# TYPO3 Extbase Parameters in Url get ignored. No action is called

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm writing an extension which checks for the browser version, and if the version isn't supported a hint is showed. 
I'm doing this with a typoscript condition, which works well so far. But in the hint is a link for the ignoring. The link should call my action "setSessionParameters" in the controller "BrowserCheck". If the link is clicked the correct url gets called, but the same output as before is shown (the hint). The action is completly ignored. I tried to put in a non existing action, but not even an exception is called, which means for me: It's not checked if the question is allowed in the ext_localconf and neither it gets checked in the controller.
I think the typoscript configuration could be a problem, but I can't find a solution. Can anyone help?
Please see my code below

ext_localconf.php:

```
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
        'VENDOR.' . $extensionKey,
        'browsercheck',
        [
            'BrowserCheck' => 'setSessionParameter',
        ],
        [
            'BrowserCheck' => 'setSessionParameter',
        ]
    );
```

page.typoscript:

```
    page = PAGE
    [session('wcobrowsercheck') == "ignore" || checkInternetExplorer()]
    page{
       //normal setup
    }
    [ELSE]
    // called setup for hint-case
    page >
    page = PAGE
    page{
        typeNum = 0
        shortcutIcon = {$files.favicon.path}
        10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
        10 {
          templateRootPaths {
              0 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/BrowserCheck
          }
          layoutRootPaths {
              0 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/BrowserCheck
          }

          templateName = MainPage
          }
          includeCSS {
            ...
           }
     }
     [END]
```

link call in the template:

```
    <f:link.action controller="BrowserCheck" action="setSessionParameters" extensionName="my_extension" pluginName="browsercheck" arguments="{ignore: 'true'}"> ignore </f:link.action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 issues with your setup.

1. You define the PAGE object twice. And the second time you wipe all previous configuration
2. I can't see that you have placed the plugin on the page.

As your question targets the second issue, I recommend adding the plugin to the page via typoscript if you want that plugin to be available everywhere.

```
page = PAGE
// ...
page.999 < tt_content.list.20.extkey_pluginname
```

Or you use a plugin that is placed on the page as a content element. Both will work. But with the current setup you cannot call the plugin as it's not present on the page.